# Entity Framework Core Model Builder Ignore Ignore<class>() configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with EntityFramework Core migration, which include abstract classes.

The main database structure contains an abstract base class, and a child class, which inherits from it's own base class, basicly one base class and one child class per table. In the type configurations I only configure the child classes, and I use `builder.Ignore<BaseClass>()` to exclude the base classes from the model. I need the ignore, because EF Core wants to map the base classes too, and I want to use Ignore method to exclude the base classes.

When I use `[NotMapped]` attribute on the base classes, the migration success, but when I use `Ignore()`, the model builder just want's to map the base classes, like I didn't call `Ignore()`.

Let's say, the DBSet contains `Test` for now, which inherits from `TestBase`
    `public virtual DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{       
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);
    modelBuilder.Ignore<TestBase>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The migration fail with base class related errors, so i think EF Core wants to map the base type too, because if I use `[NotMapped]` on `TestBase`, the migration works. The main reason why I can't use `NotMapped`, because I need the base classes in an EF generated database too, and with EF, the child classes inherits the `[NotMapped]` attribute

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you created DbSet for the base class also?

Comment: no, because I don't want to map them to db set